# Access text box to display date

Tags: ms-access

I have a database to track user errors which includes a field for the date the error occurred, titled originally enough "error date".

On the main form when the database opens I would like to add a text box or some other box type that would display the oldest error date, and update automatically if a new entry is added with an older date.

So for example among the records currently in the database the oldest error date is 10/24/2016. So would want it to display that. If I add a new record with an error date of 10/15/2016, I would want the box to update and start displaying 10/15/2016.

Any way to do this?

Comment: Thanks Chawin! That worked, naturally it was something simple lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as it is, you could use [DMin](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dmin.php).

Use the following as the control source for your text box (replace table and field names):

```
=DMin("FieldName", "TableName")
```

Comment: Thanks Chawin! That worked, naturally it was something simple lol.

Comment: @Lupi Glad it worked! Can you please mark answer as correct :)